# UITabBar get selected item

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitabbar

How can I catch the event when an item is selected from a UITabBar on iPhone/iPad app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITabBar` has a delegate property which you can use. Create a class that implements the `UITabBarDelegate` and the method:

```
– tabBar:didSelectItem:
```

will do the trick

Comment: I have A view controller which inherits  <UITABBarDelegate> in the .h file and in the .m file i have that method but it doesn't work. What I wwant ot do is to have in a ViewController a TabBar which has items dynamically loaded and whn the selected item has changed to change the content in a view control. I can't use UITabBarCOntroller because I want to create a multiplatform application.

Comment: The UITabBarController does not have to be the class that conforms to the UITabBarDelegate protocol. If it is not working I suggest you make sure you have actually set the delegate property in your code and/or in Interface Builder